# ImportError from modular django settings file

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I am trying to create a modular settings file.

Why is it that this works:

```
project/
  settings.py
  other.py
```

With this line in settings.py

```
config_module = __import__('other', globals(), locals())
```

While the following raises an ImportError:

```
project/
  settings.py
  config/
    other.py
```

With this line in settings.py:

```
config_module = __import__('config.other', globals(), locals())
```

Comment: Are you missing `__init__.py` in the config directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your config dir is missing an `__init__.py` file to make it clear you want it treated as a module. The `__init__.py` file can be empty, but it needs to exist.